# PHP get file path of an image?

Tags: php

Example:

The image url:

```
localhost/example/folder/filename.jpg
```

I want to get path of the image so it must be:

```
localhost/example/folder/
```

How to do that?

***I speak English not well. Thanks!***

I have found a solution instead of using dirname:

```
$image = 'localhost/example/folder/filename.jpg';
$directory = substr($image, 0, strrpos($image, '/', -2) + 1 );
echo $directory;
//return: localhost/example/folder/
```

Comment: use dirname('localhost/example/folder/filename.jpg')

Comment: This might help: http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get the parent folder of a file:

```
dirname("localhost/example/folder/filename.jpg");
```

See: [the doc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php)

Answer (score 7):

Use `dirname()`

```
<?php
echo dirname('localhost/example/folder/filename.jpg');
?>
```